# Deployment fails with .NET error even though the app is NOT .NET

Tags: deployment, build, ibm-cloud

I have had an app running for some time on Bluemix. When I tweaked something small in one of the web pages & rebuilt/redeployed, it failed with the following message in the log:
"The project app does not specify any target frameworks in /tmp/staged/app/project.json."

The log indicates that it's trying to do stuff with .NET, saying "Installing dotnet CLI" among others. It looks like the issue is a sudden desire, on the part of the build process, to include some ASP.NET features, even though it's all node.js and I definitely absolutely do not want any of that .NET stuff near my app.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the .NET buildpack is detecting your application before it gets to the NodeJS buildpack, you can force it to use the NodeJS buildpack by specifying that buildpack from the command-line like so:

`cf push <app_name> -b sdk-for-nodejs`

Alternatively, you can provide a `manifest.yml` file in your application which will also specify the buildpack to be used.  The format of that file would be similar to this:

```
---
applications:
- name: <app_name>
buildpack: sdk-for-nodejs
```

In both cases you would replace `<app_name>` with the actual name of your app that you want to use in Bluemix.

Comment: Thank you - updating the `manifest.yml` fixed the problem. What I still don't understand is why Bluemix decided to go off and use .Net but, at this point, I don't particularly care!